# used in a worksheet cell, a number from a result string of an html API query

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

How I can make the example below appear in a cell:

1 / the libreoffice calc cell queries a url:
"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT"

2 / the libreoffice calc cell extracts the data from the chain:
{"symbol": "BTCUSDT", "price": "23062.02000000"}

3 / Result displayed in cell '23062.02000000',

is it reasonable to try to resolve this expectation !?

Answer (score 0):

After entering your link, when the Text import window opens, select Other, set double quote `"` as the delimiter. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on all column headings except the price, right-click select Hide. Only the price must remain Standard. Click OK. Only the price will be shown on the cell. Format the cell to display the desired amount of decimal places.

[image]